# Stop 'alt' from being added to the_post_thumbnail

Tags: thumbnails

I'm using the_post_thumbnail to display a specific thumbnail size. The function outputs an 'alt=' tag with the description of the attachment. Is it possible to clear the value in the ouput? So it'll display `alt=""`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail you will see that you can change the alt. You have to add an array with the value for the alt in the second parameter like so: `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array( 'alt' => false )); ?>`

Comment: No effect for me on latest version.